# Installing a custom package in MAC OS X and making it available to all applications

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have created a package or framework and I would like to install it in:  /Library/Frameworks so that it could be available for all applications. I dragged it onto that path but it seems that the applications can't see it after set up the corresponding reference in the application . Does Anyone knows what else I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode, paths such as `/Library/Frameworks` get the base SDK path prepended, as defined in `SDKROOT`. So during a build your framework needs to be visible at `$(SDKROOT)/Library/Frameworks` which might be e.g. `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/Library/Frameworks`. You can either install your framework there, or you can keep it in `/Library/Frameworks` and add a symbolic link to it in `$(SDKROOT)/Library/Frameworks`.